# Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n!}{10^n}$ not converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**The question:**
Test the following series for convergence or divergence: 
$$
\frac{1!}{10}-\frac{2!}{10^2}+\frac{3!}{10^3}-\frac{4!}{10^4}+\cdots
$$
**My answer:**
The general term is then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n!}{10^n}
$$
and using the alternating series test $u_{n+1}<u_n$ for all $n\ge1$ and $u_n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

for $n=1$:$u_n=0.1$
for $n=2$:$u_n=0.02$
for $n=3$:$u_n=0.006$
for $n=4$:$u_n=0.0024$
$\cdots$

Help

Comment: Hint: For $n\geq 10$, $u_n\geq u_{n-1}$

Comment: The series $\sum \frac{1}{u_n}$ converges, so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}|=\frac{n+1}{10}$. $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}| > 1$. So the series diverges, by [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Comment: I don't like the choise of words here, because convergence to $1$ doesn't mean anything about the convergence of the series.

Comment: @Belgi: It is a sufficient condition. $L\to \infty$ means the series diverges.

Comment: But thats not written, you gave the argument "does not converge to 1" which says nothing...still, "This diverges away from 1 " doesn't say what you want - it can diverge from $1$ when it convergers to say $0.5$. just write L tends to infinity as in the comment or say that the elements of the sequence does not tend to $0$...

Comment: @Belgi: ya thanks, got to have been careful about these things!

Comment: I have changed my vote accordingly :)

Answer (score 11):

The general term does not go to 0.  Therefore, the sum does not converge.  You can not determine if the terms $u_n$ go to 0 just by looking at a few of them, i.e., you can not determine a limit by looking at a few values.  When $n$ is small, increasing by 1 makes the denominator increase by a factor of 10, but the numerator only increases by a factor of 1 or 2 or 3.  But, once $n \geq 10$, now the numerator starts increasing faster than the denominator.

In this case, $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n = \infty$.  Do you see why?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n!}{10^n}=\infty$, so that $\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}n!}{10^n}$ does nort converge to $0$.